# Does Python3.8 version on CentOS8 support autocomplete format?

Tags: autocomplete, python-3.8, centos8

I've installed Python 3.8 version on RHEL Linux CentOS 8 core. When I try to type any python in-built functions partially and press "Tab" button to make it auto-complete, I'm not able to see Python3.8 is not auto-completing any functions of Python. Even I can't see history of executed python commands if I press Up-Arrow mark in Python3.8.

But, I could see auto-complete feature in its previous versions of Python3.6. Just wanted to know whether Python3.8 supports auto-complete feature? This is the below Python3.8 version details which I had installed.

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  4 2020, 10:47:18) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: You may need to install `readline-devel `, then run configure and make again.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the response. I installed " readline-devel-7.0-10.el8.x86_64" and "readline-devel-7.0-10.el8.i686 " and checked. It seems it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even I installed autocomplete in python3.8 by running command - "pip3.8 install autocomplete". Then checked. But it didn't !

Comment: Hmm. I could not reproduce your error on Fedora 30, that is, if I install readline-devel and run configure and make again, I do get a Python with tab completion . I'll download CentOS 8 and try it there. If you run `yourpython3.8 -v`, does it say that it's trying to load the `readline` module?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I understood difference in readline by running `python3.8 -v`  `python3.6 -v`.I could see output of readline is in python3.6 but not in 3.8.Below is the output on python3.6 where `readline` module is there.But same couldn't see on `python3.8 -v`
`#extension module 'readline' loaded from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#extension module 'readline' executed from '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
import 'readline' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x7fe0faf54908>`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sure, if you happen to see on RHEL CentOS 8 by any chance, please let me know :)

Comment: Installing `readline-devel` on CentOS 8 followed by `./configure` and `make` gives me a `./python` that has tab completion. (And building it without libreadline-devel gives me a python that doesn't have tab completion.) Can you do `grep HAVE_LIBREADLINE config.status` to see whether your configure script found it?